# Death of Grothendieck

Tags: discussion

I am sorry to report the sad news that Grothendieck has died.

Comment: See also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/187106/grothendieck-sad-news

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Grothendieck

Comment: Thank you, Groethendieck, for your ideas. You will be unforgettable for a very long time.

Comment: New York Times obituary, http://www.nytimes.com/2014/11/16/world/europe/alexander-grothendieck-math-enigma-dies-at-86.html

Comment: I like the New York Times explanation that you have to pronounce "GROAT-en-deek" (which is amusing but perfectly correct). The sentence "*Mr. Grothendieck’s work was also a steppingstone to solutions of enigmas famous among mathematicians — the Poincaré conjecture, for instance — but far more arcane*" is to say the least ambiguous or, less charitably, completely false.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: yes, I noticed that sentence. It seems to achieve the rare feat of being simultaneously false (suggesting Grothendieck's work contributed to solving the Poincare conjecture) and meaningless (because whatever the intended meaning, it should be preserved when the parenthetical part is removed, but here that results in a non-well-formed sentence). Still, at least the NYT honoured him with an obituary, unlike some other "serious" newspapers in the Anglophone world.

Comment: Ah, now that I follow Gerry Myerson's link, I see they have replaced the offending text with something much better:  _Mr. Grothendieck’s work was also a steppingstone to solutions of other enigmas famous among mathematicians, but far more arcane._ Now it is clear what _other_ and _more_ refer to, namely Fermat's Last Theorem (discussed in the preceding paragraph). Well done, NYT!

Comment: Dear @Asal: I am amazed how honestly and  competently the NYT edited its article. I don't know many newspapers which would have reacted that way. Well done indeed !